# JQuery Get Value of input in iframe page returning Object

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get the value of an input which is in an iframe.

When I submit the form I'm getting the alert telling me it's been submitted but when I try to get the value of the input it's alerting Object instead of the value.

Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myiframe').load(function() {
        $(this).contents().find('#myiframe').submit(function() {

            $res = $("#myiframe").contents().find('input[name="subject"]');

            alert('Form HAS been submitted'); //This works

            alert($res); // returns Object Object

            return true;
        });
    });

});
```

What I'm I doing wrong here?

Comment: tried alert($res.val()); ?

Comment: Yes, that won't alert for some reason

Comment: can you show us the html in iframe?

Comment: what about `alert($($res).val())` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$res` is a jquery object. You need to get the value using `.val()` inorder to alert the value.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myiframe').load(function() {
        $(this).contents().find('#myiframe').submit(function() {

            $res = $("#myiframe").contents().find('input[name="subject"]');

            alert('Form HAS been submitted'); //This works

            alert($res.val()); // returns Object Object

            return true;
        });
    });

});
```

Answer (score 2):

It is because you are getting an object back. Try querying for the value instead.

```
// ..
    alert($res.val())
// ..
```

Comment: what is the need of $() again?

Comment: @AnoopJoshi A '$' in a variable means nothing to the interpreter, much like an underscore. So if jQuery is not bound to the fetched element one would still be able to call jquery funcntions such as val() if enquoted with $()

Comment: Thats not my question. In his code $res is already a jquery object. You dont need to make it again as jquery object by wrapping up with $()